# Выделение цветом TableRow по условию

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

Имеются две таблицы:

```
@FXML
TableView<FrameGroupIntersections> tvOldGroups;
@FXML
TableView<FrameGroupIntersections> tvNewGroups;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данные в них связанны в классе:

```
public class FrameGroupIntersections {

    private FrameGroup group;

    private ObservableMap<FrameGroupIntersections,IntTypeInfoWrapper> intersections;

    private BooleanProperty hasErr;

    FrameGroupIntersections (FrameGroup group, Map<FrameGroupIntersections,IntTypeInfoWrapper> intersections){
        this.group = group;
        hasErr = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
        setIntersections(intersections);
    }

    FrameGroupIntersections(FrameGroup group){
        this(group,null);
    }
}
```

Т.е. `FrameGroupIntersections` из левой таблицы имеет в мапе пересечений ссылку на `FrameGroupIntersections` из правой, и наоборот.

Необходимо, чтобы при выделении любого из `FrameGroupIntersections` в соседней таблице связанные с ним пересечения подсвечивались каким-либо цветом, т.е. менялся `TableRow.styleProperty()`. Подскажите, каким образом этого можно достичь?

Comment: Вам не обьекты нужно связывать а таблицы.Реакцию на выделение сформируйте и расширте на соседнюю таблицу...

Comment: @PeterSlusar в том и дело, что я не понимаю, как имея связь в объектах связать таблицы и "расширить на соседнюю таблицу". Был бы Вам очень признателен, если бы вы привели пример.